# How to activate a window of an external application

Tags: c#, c++, windows

I've used FindWindow to get a handle to a window of an external application. How can I use this handle to activate the window of the external application, if it is minimized or behind other applications on the windows desktop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent focus-stealing (or at least make accidental focus-stealing harder), Windows puts up some roadblocks to one process bringing another process's window to the top.

Check MSDN for [SetForegroundWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633539(v=VS.85).aspx) (especially in the Remarks section) and [AllowSetForegroundWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632668(v=VS.85).aspx).

You should either send a message to the process to tell it to restore its own window, or that process has to explicitly allow your process to do this.

Answer (score 0):

FindWindow() followed by ShowWindow().

Comment: I tried ShowWindow and BringWindowToTop with no success, do they work on the windows of external processes?

Comment: As long as you have successfully retrieved a handle to that window.